# error: Can't create or modify index in space: index id too big

Tags: tarantool

ive got a temp space as a buffer, so i update indexes before inserting and deleting them after tuples are moved to another space.
some time after got this error:
*Can't create or modify index in space: index id too big *

ive tried increasing number of indexes by box.schema.INDEX_MAX but that didnt help.
in the docs written that index id = last index id + 1, so ive reached some kind of limit? cannot find anything about max index id.
anyone has an idea?

Comment: Are you re-creating the same index each time? If so, it look as the root of the problem. I can't say much without a clear description what you want to achieve and how exactly you're doing that.

Answer (score 0):

There is "[Number of indexes in a space](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/book/box/limitations/)" limitation exists, which is 128.
So, you can't change it (without modifying Tarantool source code and building your own variant).